# Removing the 'Leave a comment' link on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I want my 'Leave a comment' section to not link to the comment.php file as I'm going to use it for toggling instead.

Here is the code:

```
<span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0 Comments', 'Bomb!' ), __( '1 Comment', 'Bomb!' ), __( '% Comments', 'Bomb!' ) ) ?></span>
```

I'm a bit of a PHP noob so I'm wondering how to remove the comments_popup_link part without ruining the number of comments displayed.

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com can help you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user1636968

Per you need you can toggle comments from your Post or Page in WordPress by Check/Unchecked Allow comments in Discussion Section just underneath WYSIWYG Area of your Post/Page.

Also there is **Screen Options** expandable section (underneath User Info) in top right of WordPress Admin, from where you can choose what to types of section you want to have in your post/page in WordPress.

Check attached image for more detail information.[image: toggling comments in wordpress]

Also, you can take a look at below ref. to customized WordPress admin...

http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-wordpress-admin-area/

Here is one more ref. which adddress same problem like you have...
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11222/is-there-any-way-to-remove-comments-function-and-section-totally

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is in the CSS, not in the PHP code, although my wordpress-fu is a bit rusty.

Try this in your CSS file:

```
.comments-link { display: none; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately display:none removes the whole thing. :(